# Using Printwriter in servlet response

Tags: java, servlets, response, crystal-reports-2008, printwriter

In this [link](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/JRC_SDK/jrc_viewersjava_api_doc/doc/jrcsdk_java_viewers_apiRef/com/crystaldecisions/report/web/ServerControl.html#processHttpRequest%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.ServletContext,%20java.io.Writer%29) it says:Handles the user's request to generate the HTML for the report and writes the HTML directly to the response object.
Now in my code, I have:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
crystalReportViewer.processHttpRequest(request, response, context,null);
```

If I understand correctly, the `processHttpRequest` will itself do something like `response.getWriter().print(.....).`

So is the code creating 2 instances of `PrintWriter`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Response object will return the same writer every time. You can use these writers interchangeably:

```
final PrintWriter writerA = response.getWriter();
final PrintWriter writerB = response.getWriter();
writerA.println("A1");
writerB.println("B1");
writerA.println("A2");
writerB.println("B2");
```

The output is as expected because `writerA` and `writerB` are actually pointing to the exact same instance of `PrintWriter`.

I don't know whether it is stated as such in the specification, the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) only says:

> Either this method or getOutputStream() may be called to write the body, not both.

That being said your code is not safe for two reasons:

- `crystalReportViewer` might call `response.getOutputStream()` which breaks the contract quoted above
- if you print something first and then pass the `response` to the `crystalReportViewer` chances are your output will break the `crystalReportViewer` output as it will be prepended.